# Spring - applicationContext getBeansWithAnnotation method returns an empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

My question is about getBeansWithAnnotation method.

I have a custom annotation named MyCustomAnnotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {

    String group() default "DEFAULT_GROUP";
}
```

I also have a listener class like below:

```
public class MyCustomAnnotationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = event.getApplicationContext();
        Map<String, Object> myCustomAnnotationBeans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(MyCustomAnnotation.class);
    }
}
```

I have configured my application-context.xml to scan components with MyCustomAnnotation.

```
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.annotations.MyCustomAnnotation"/>
```

I can get the list of beans which are annotated with MyCustomAnnotation during initial startup of my application using getBeansWithAnnotation method in MyCustomAnnotationListener.

My question is why this method returns an empty list when it is triggered the second time.

Thanks

Comment: when will you invoke 2nd times? actually , as your `@MyCustomAnnotation` is also marked with `@Component` , it will be picked up by Spring by default , no need to set the `include-filter`

Comment: I do not invoke refresh event manually; it is invoked right after the first time.

Comment: You mean `MyCustomAnnotationListener#onApplicationEvent ` invoke 2 times ?

Comment: Yes you are right; it invokes two times. During the first one I got the beans with annotations; and during the second call I got an empty map.

Comment: They are the same context ? (Check by `applicationContext.getId()`)  . Your context has a parent context?

Comment: It turns out that it was invoked 2 times because there was a child context in my application; I wasn't aware that this method being invoked 2 times is not regular. I thought the problem was my annotation configuration. Now I can only make this method work for the parent context. Thanks @KenChan! Your question helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @KenChan; there is no check mark besides your answer so I couldn't accept it. But this definitely solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear you solve the problem .I summaries it as an answer . It would be nice if you would accept my answer and of course if you like , give me a vote up please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextRefreshedEvent` should happen once during bootstrapping the context. It will publish the event to the context itself and all of its parent contexts.

Now its listener (i.e `MyCustomAnnotationListener`) executes 2 times suggesting that your context may have a parent context .The `@MyCustomAnnotation` beans are defined in child context , and so the parent context cannot find it and empty list is return when `MyCustomAnnotationListener` runs for the parent context.

You may verify if the context are the same using `applicationContext.getId()`.

BTW : As `@MyCustomAnnotation` is also marked with `@Component` , it will be picked up by Spring by default , no need to set the `include-filter`.